# How to check all first 5 characters of all lines for specific word in txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python to make a simple info retrieving program that gets a clientID and a client id for a user is the first 5 characters of every line the txt file looks like this

```
RYMAU
ELOWE
RUKUM
KLKID
LAJON
```

I want for a user to enter a 5 letter id and check through each line for one of those specific client ids at the moment i have come up with this :

```
clientID = input('Enter your clientID : ')

fob = open('clientRecords.txt', 'r') # opens file stores it in a var called fob and reads from it
if (clientID in fob.readline(5)):
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('Access denied')
fob.close()
```

But this only checks the first 5 letters of the first line not all of them.

This is how the text file actually looks:

```
NeQua,High,Running,5,Swimming,40,Aerobics,40,Football,20,Tennis,10
ImKol,Moderate,Walking,40,Hiking,0,Cleaning,40,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,20
YoTri,Moderate,Walking,20,Hiking,30,Cleaning,40,Skateboarding,20,Basketball,40
RoDen,High,Running,20,Swimming,20,Aerobics,40,Football,30,Tennis,50
NaThe,Moderate,Walking,30,Hiking,30,Cleaning,20,Skateboarding,10,Basketball,30
ReWes,Moderate,Walking,30,Hiking,20,Cleaning,50,Skateboarding,40,Basketball,20
BrFre,High,Running,20,Swimming,30,Aerobics,30,Football,30,Tennis,20
KaDat,High,Running,30,Swimming,20,Aerobics,10,Football,20,Tennis,30
ViRil,High,Running,50,Swimming,50,Aerobics,60,Football,40,Tennis,50
TrGeo,High,Running,10,Swimming,20,Aerobics,30,Football,30,Tennis,20
DaWay,High,Running,60,Swimming,50,Aerobics,40,Football,50,Tennis,50
CaAma,High,Running,30,Swimming,20,Aerobics,10,Football,20,Tennis,30
ArRes,High,Running,0,Swimming,10,Aerobics,30,Football,20,Tennis,20
BeVic,High,Running,20,Swimming,20,Aerobics,30,Football,30,Tennis,10
MaFre,High,Running,10,Swimming,20,Aerobics,20,Football,40,Tennis,30
AnMer,Moderate,Walking,40,Hiking,30,Cleaning,30,Skateboarding,20,Basketball,30
SaBro,Moderate,Walking,30,Hiking,20,Cleaning,30,Skateboarding,20,Basketball,20
PoLig,Moderate,Walking,20,Hiking,20,Cleaning,20,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,30
HeZbe,Moderate,Walking,30,Hiking,40,Cleaning,20,Skateboarding,40,Basketball,10
GiLop,Moderate,Walking,40,Hiking,0,Cleaning,30,Skateboarding,40,Basketball,20
DeTur,Moderate,Walking,10,Hiking,0,Cleaning,10,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,30
LaKin,Moderate,Walking,20,Hiking,20,Cleaning,30,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,20
AnVen,Moderate,Walking,50,Hiking,0,Cleaning,50,Skateboarding,50,Basketball,20
LoLew,Moderate,Walking,10,Hiking,20,Cleaning,10,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,40
NyRed,Moderate,Walking,0,Hiking,0,Cleaning,0,Skateboarding,0,Basketball,20
```

Comment: Read file into a list where every line is an element of the list. Much easier to check for your ID then

Comment: What do you mean the client ID is the first 5 characters of every line? The file example you have above starts with different characters on each line..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to read all the lines, and test the first five characters of each line:

```
with open('clientRecords.txt') as fob:
    allowed_access = any(line.startswith(clientID) for line in fob)
if allowed_access:
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('Access denied')
```

`allowed_access` will be `True` if any line in the file starts with the provided prefix, and it will stop checking lines as soon as it finds a hit.

Note: To avoid cheating, you probably want to verify that the provided `clientID` is actually five characters long.

If you want to get the line associated with that ID, not just whether or not the ID exists, you can modify that check to:

```
with open('clientRecords.txt') as fob:
    access_data = next((line for line in fob if line.startswith(clientID)), None)
if access_data is not None:  # clientID exists, and access_data is the line it was found on
```

Also, if you'll be performing this test a lot, and the records file rarely changes, you may want to cache in memory to reduce I/O work. You'd load the valid IDs in once up front (not in any loop or event handler that validates users):

```
with open('clientRecords.txt') as fob:
    known_users = {line[:5] for line in fob}
```

Then your per login test simplifies to:

```
if clientID in known_users:
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('Access denied')
```

which will run (for all intents and purposes) instantly, vs. the meaningful cost in reopening and rereading the file on each test. You'd probably want a staleness timeout after which you'd recache the `known_users`, or `os.stat` the file every once in a while and recache if it's modified.

The version that gets the associated line is:

```
with open('clientRecords.txt') as fob:
    known_users = {line[:5]: line for line in fob}
```

and to check/lookup:

```
access_data = known_users.get(clientID)  # Returns None if the clientID is not found, or the complete line if it is found
if access_data is not None:
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('Access denied')
```

Comment: Or `line.startswith(clientID, 0, 5)`.

Comment: @KevinGuan: Does the explicit start/end gain you anything? I mean, the main worry is they give too short a `clientID` (which explicit `start`/`end` doesn't fix, right?), and any check to require it to be five characters long would let you exclude too long values too anyway.

Comment: how would i go about giving a condition to this for example printing access granted if it finds the clientID ?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, yeah. Just a tip.

Comment: @techedryan What about add this into your question?

Comment: @techedryan: I added the test; I assumed the test was simple enough that it wasn't necessary to include code you'd already written (since `allowed_access` is a `bool` that means "is access granted", and you'd just test it directly to replace the bad test in the question).

Comment: @ShadowRanger how would i go about finding specific values in the line of the clientID so that i would check if high or moderate is next of the clientID.

Comment: `line.startswith(clientID + ',')`